# Magnified plot / Vertical Markers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I've been trying to use the `spy` library to magnify a part of my plot, but I don't really understand how it works, and I can't find a manual/tutorial anywhere.

Right now I am doing something based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100597/16537) for the magnification part, although not exactly what I was looking for, might do the trick.

[image]

However, my question is how exactly do I get the "x 2000" line, along with the second plot?

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18720/2552

Comment: Interesting alternative, but I was looking for something that actually enlarges the scale, not just zooms the image.

Comment: Then you don't want the `spy` library, because that's what it does. I think your best bet is to just use a second `axis` environment.

Comment: For the zooming part, maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59036/using-tikzlibrary-spy-without-magnifying-line-width-and-or-mark-size and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116637/rectangular-spy-in-pgfplots-without-scaling?lq=1 is more what you're looking for. It would be good if you could edit your question to explain in more detail what output you're looking for exactly though. Also, I think it's best if you start a new question about the vertical lines, since that seems unrelated to the zooming issue.