# Background fill with pgfplots inset

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I am trying to add an inset to a plot. I used [this answer as a guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18716/inset-plot-with-pgfplots) to get started, but the inset plot is transparent. Adding `axis background/.style={fill=white}` to the inset plot fixes the background, but not in the surrounding axis labels. Is there a way I can extend this to cover the whole region? I think the issue is clear from the image below:

[image: Inset plot with issue]

I am not using the `spy` library as I am using a more detailed data file for the inset.

```
\begin{figure} % CONTINUOUS SCAN INSET
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width = 14cm,
    height = 8cm,
    title = {50 $\mu$m scintillator probe continuous scan},
    xlabel = {Position (mm)},
    ylabel = {Response (\% of Maximum)},
    axis lines = left,
    ymax = 110,
    ymin=0,
    xmin = 3,
]
\addplot[blue] table[x=x,y=y]{../../AS Data/ProcessedData/50um-profile.txt};
\coordinate (insetPosition) at (rel axis cs:0.35,0.15);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[at={(insetPosition)},anchor={outer south west},footnotesize,axis background/.style={fill=white},
    axis lines = left,
    ymax = 110,
    ymin=0,
    xmin = 19,
    xmax = 21,
    xtick = {19,19.4,...,21}
]
\addplot[blue] table[x=x,y=y]{../../AS Data/ProcessedData/50um-profile-subsection-small.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Continuous scan through the field (inset).}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Although the question handles a totally different topic, I think my answer given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358296/95441 should answer your question, right?

Comment: @StefanPinnow yes, that does work for me, thanks! I'll write the working code up as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Stefan Pinnow for [linking a relevant solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358296/95441). Declaring new pgf layers before the axes:

`\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}`

Nesting each axis inside the appropriate layer using:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
```

etc and setting the main layer to include a white rectangle achieves the desired result:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \fill [black!0] ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}] insetAxis.outer south west)
        rectangle    ([shift={(+5pt,+5pt)}] insetAxis.outer north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

Complete TeX code:

```
\begin{figure} % CONTINUOUS SCAN INSET

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\begin{axis}[
    width = 14cm,
    height = 8cm,
    title = {50 $\mu$m scintillator probe continuous scan},
    xlabel = {Position (mm)},
    ylabel = {Response (\% of Maximum)},
    axis lines = left,
    ymax = 110,
    ymin=0,
    xmin = 3,
]
\addplot[blue] table[x=x,y=y]{../../AS Data/ProcessedData/50um-profile.txt};
\coordinate (insetPosition) at (rel axis cs:0.35,0.15);
\end{axis}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\begin{axis}[at={(insetPosition)},anchor={outer south west},footnotesize,axis background/.style={fill=white},
    axis lines = left,
    ymax = 110,
    ymin=0,
    xmin = 19,
    xmax = 21,
    xtick = {19,19.4,...,21},
    name = insetAxis
]
\addplot[blue] table[x=x,y=y]{../../AS Data/ProcessedData/50um-profile-subsection-small.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{pgfonlayer}

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
        \fill [black!0] ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}] insetAxis.outer south west)
            rectangle    ([shift={(+5pt,+5pt)}] insetAxis.outer north east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Continuous scan through the field (inset).}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Great that it helped you. But instead of answering your own question with "my solution" you could have asked me, if I want to answer it. Or at least it would have been nice if you would have upvoted my answer, if it helped you ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow Sorry, you're right. I assumed that if you wanted to write it up, you would have done so, rather than comment. My bad.